Algebra structure on the Clifford irreducible representation
The Clifford algebra associated to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ or $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ with the canonical scalar product, call it $Cl(n)$, has a unique irreducible left representation $V$ (which in contrast with the Heisenberg algebra's unique irreducible representation is finite), and I think this is the set of what physicists call spinors. So we get a surjection of vector spaces $Cl(n) \longrightarrow V$ by choosing any non-zero vector and having $Cl(n)$ act on it. Is the kernel of this surjections a bilateral ideal, i.e., is this the way physicists multiply (and take the conjugate of) spinors? If not, how do they do it?

The kernel is a left ideal.

Yes, do you mean to say it's not a bilateral ideal?

Maybe you could point to a reference where "physicists multiply spinors" so that people can see what that looks like?

Sure, sorry. For instance in https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~claire.voisin/Articlesweb/Voisin_symetrie_miroir.pdf (in French, top of page 42), she mentions that the spinors for $\mathbb{R}^2$ are combinations two grassmann numbers $\theta_{1,2}$, and for a physicist see https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0207142v1 page 35 in the definition of the supersymmetry operator where he multiplies a majorana fermion and a constant $\mathbb{R}^2$ spinor

In Claire Voisin's text there is no multiplication of spinors going on that I can see, and in the other text spinors are only multiplied by complex scalars (they put two vectors/spinors in a column and multiply that by a 2-by-2 complex matrix, this only uses the vector space structure and no internal multiplication). So your example do not lead me to believe very strongly that such a multiplication exists.

I might be wrong but I think there is because you can multiply grassmann numbers, they generate the (three dimensional) free anticommutative algebra on two letters, and I think that what Voisin means by her identifying the thetas with the spinors is that this is the same multiplication as for the spinors. Also I don’t precisely understand what you said about the susy operator but I would argue that you just described spinor multiplication in this particular case. Anyway there is also the conjugation of spinors which I think you will admit exists
